# Determining the truth value of a given statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

"There exist *a,b* ∈ ℝ such that {*x* ∈ ℝ | *ax^2 = b*} = ∅"

I am not quite sure where to start. I do see many sets of *a,b,x* that satisfies *ax^2 = b*, but I am not sure what it means by it is equal to an empty set, *∅*.

Am I completely on the wrong track? Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The empty set means that there are no values of $x$ that solve the equation $ax^2=b$.  Now if $a=b=1$ then there _indeed are_ values of $x$ that solve $x^2=1$: $$ \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2=1\} = \{-1,1\}$$ Is it solvable for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Note that $x^2$ can never be negative.

Comment: @Michael Aha, it's more clear now. What about *a = b = 0* then? Will this make it:

{  ∈ ℝ : 0 = 0 } = { } ? I'm not sure if this is correct reasoning.

Comment: When $a=b=0$, then all $x$ satisfy the condition, $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : 0x^2=0\}=\mathbb{R} \neq \{\}$. What about $a=1$, $b=-1$? (The set in question is the empty set if no real number $x$ exists that fullfils the condition)

Comment: I understand now. I was misunderstanding the statement {x ∈ ℝ | ax^2 = b} = ∅. Thank you for helping!